Question not visible in the list of questions under a tag
My question isn't visible in the lists of questions of any of the three tags that were added. I searched using "No accepted answers" filter and went till Feb 11, 2022 (the date on which it was asked), but it isn't there.

By "Questions with no acceptable answers" you mean using this filter. Or do you mean searching with hasaccepted:no, or something else?

@MartinSleziak Yeah, that first filter you mentioned.

But the filter says "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers". You question has several upvoted answers.

@MartinSleziak Oh thank you. I didn't read that line appearing at the top. I just read "No accepted answer" in front of that filter's checkbox.

Yes, I certainly agree that it's rather confusing that the filter is called just "No accepted answer" and after applying the filter it says "no upvoted or accepted answers".
